# Can't resolve 'node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css' in 'C:\Users\ayusz\Desktop\ay-dash'

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, angular16, angular-kendo

I was working on my angular progect, but then i had to restart my pc, when i re started the ng-serve,
i get error of Can't resolve 'node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css' in 'C:\Users\ayusz\Desktop\ay-dash'

i have seen this error for first time, and dont know about it.
also there is no directory as "[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SStFa.png)~/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css" in my project

i have run npm install @progress/kendo-theme-default --save
but it still dont work

Comment: Can you try to delete `node_modules` and `npm install` again?